# magento2 controller concept of rendering layouts

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I just started working with magento 2 and I am little confuse how does the controller know that which layout has to be rendered.

Comment: go through [this](https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/view-block-layout-template-magento-2.html) link. Hopefully, it'd help.

Comment: This extension is useful for debugging layout handles https://github.com/mgtcommerce/Mgt_Developertoolbar